# How to change the Text color of a Javascript element on a HTML document

Tags: javascript

I have created a paragraph element with the class story in the html for my javascript to populate. How can I change the text color of itemX, itemY, itemZ so that they stand out from the rest of the storyText string once the button is pressed?

Since the newStory string isn't created in the html document until after the JS button is pressed I am confused on how to target the itemXYZ variables.

```js
//1. COMPLETE VARIABLE AND FUNCTION DEFINITIONS

var customName = document.getElementById('customname');
var randomize = document.querySelector('.randomize');
var story = document.querySelector('.story');

function randomValueFromArray(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

//2. TEXT STRINGS
let insertX = ['Willy the Goblin', 'Big Daddy', 'Father Christmas'];
let insertY = ['the soup kitchen', 'Disneyland', 'the White House'];
let insertZ = ['spontaneously combusted', 'melted into a puddle on the sidewalk', 'turned into a slug and crawled away'];

//3. EVENT LISTENER AND PARTIAL FUNCTION DEFINITION

randomize.addEventListener('click', result);

function result() {


  let itemX = randomValueFromArray(insertX);
  let itemY = randomValueFromArray(insertY);
  let itemZ = randomValueFromArray(insertZ);

  //replaces inserts in stortText w/ randomized strings from itemX,Y,Z
  let newStory = `It was 94 fahrenheit outside, so ${itemX} went for a walk. When they got to ${itemY}, they stared in horror for a few moments, then ${itemZ}. Bob saw the whole thing, but was not surprised — ${itemX} weighs 300 pounds, and it was a hot day.`;

  //replaces 'Bob' w/ custom name if given
  if (customName.value !== '') {
    let name = customName.value;
    newStory = newStory.replace('Bob', name);
  }

  //converts fahrenheit to centigrade & pounds to stone
  if (document.getElementById("uk").checked) {
    let temperature = Math.round((94 - 32) * 5 / 9) + ' centigrade';
    let weight = Math.round(300 * 0.071429) + ' stone';
    newStory = newStory.replace('94 fahrenheit', temperature);
    newStory = newStory.replace('300 pounds', weight);
  }

  story.textContent = newStory;
  story.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 350px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}

p {
  background: #FFC125;
  color: #5E2612;
  padding: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="generatorStyles.css">

  <title>Silly story generator</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <label for="customname">Enter custom name:</label>
    <input id="customname" type="text" placeholder="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="us">US</label><input id="us" type="radio" name="ukus" value="us" checked>
    <label for="uk">UK</label><input id="uk" type="radio" name="ukus" value="uk">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="randomize">Generate random story</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Thanks a lot to Willy Aguirre for his help with the code for this assessment -->
  <p class="story"></p>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap `itemX, itemY and itemZ` each with a `span` as following

```
<span class="itemY">${itemY}</span>
<span class="itemX">${itemX}</span>
<span class="itemZ">${itemZ}</span>
```

Then you can set `innerHTML` property of your **`story`** with above HTML string. Now you can select those `span`s by their respective class name and set their styles accordingly.

Demo:

```js
//1. COMPLETE VARIABLE AND FUNCTION DEFINITIONS

var customName = document.getElementById("customname");
var randomize = document.querySelector(".randomize");
var story = document.querySelector(".story");

function randomValueFromArray(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

//2. TEXT STRINGS
let insertX = ["Willy the Goblin", "Big Daddy", "Father Christmas"];
let insertY = ["the soup kitchen", "Disneyland", "the White House"];
let insertZ = [
  "spontaneously combusted",
  "melted into a puddle on the sidewalk",
  "turned into a slug and crawled away"
];

//3. EVENT LISTENER AND PARTIAL FUNCTION DEFINITION

randomize.addEventListener("click", result);

function result() {
  let itemX = randomValueFromArray(insertX);
  let itemY = randomValueFromArray(insertY);
  let itemZ = randomValueFromArray(insertZ);

  //replaces inserts in stortText w/ randomized strings from itemX,Y,Z
  let newStory = `It was 94 fahrenheit outside, so <span class="itemX">${itemX}</span> went for a walk. When they got to <span class="itemY">${itemY}</span>, they stared in horror for a few moments, then <span class="itemZ">${itemZ}</span>. Bob saw the whole thing, but was not surprised — <span class="itemX">${itemX}</span> weighs 300 pounds, and it was a hot day.`;

  //replaces 'Bob' w/ custom name if given
  if (customName.value !== "") {
    let name = customName.value;
    newStory = newStory.replace("Bob", name);
  }

  //converts fahrenheit to centigrade & pounds to stone
  if (document.getElementById("uk").checked) {
    let temperature = Math.round((94 - 32) * 5 / 9) + " centigrade";
    let weight = Math.round(300 * 0.071429) + " stone";
    newStory = newStory.replace("94 fahrenheit", temperature);
    newStory = newStory.replace("300 pounds", weight);
  }

  story.innerHTML = newStory;
  story.style.visibility = "visible";

  let spanX = story.getElementsByClassName("itemX");
  let spanY = story.getElementsByClassName("itemY");
  let spanZ = story.getElementsByClassName("itemZ");

  function setColor(arr, color) {
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i].style.color = color;
    }
  }

  setColor(spanX,'red');
  setColor(spanY,'green');
  setColor(spanZ,'blue');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 350px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}

p {
  background: #ffc125;
  color: #5e2612;
  padding: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="customname">Enter custom name:</label>
  <input id="customname" type="text" placeholder="">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="us">US</label><input id="us" type="radio" name="ukus" value="us" checked>
  <label for="uk">UK</label><input id="uk" type="radio" name="ukus" value="uk">
</div>
<div>
  <button class="randomize">Generate random story</button>
</div>
<!-- Thanks a lot to Willy Aguirre for his help with the code for this assessment -->
<p class="story"></p>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your functions with an event handle, when the user presses the button.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Comment: Isn't this the event handler: randomize.addEventListener('click', result);? I'm still confused on how to target just a word or phrase though?

Comment: Actually, the above answer provided by Elish, works for me.